# Не работает spritecollide в pygame. AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'colliderect'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, коллизии

Пишу игру на pygame. Решил настроить коллизию со вторым игроком и группой пуль при помощи `pygame.sprite.spritecollide`.

Вылезает ошибка в методе `collusion()`.
Ошибка: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'colliderect'`.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Код:

```
import json  # Модули для разработки
import math
import pygame

from keys import KEYS1, KEYS2  # Словари с клавишами


class App:  # Основной класс игры
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        with open("sprite_conf.json") as load_img:  # Загрузка json конфига с путями к спрайтам
            self.data = json.load(load_img)
        self.background_img = pygame.image.load(self.data["background"])

        self.fps = 60  # Параметры главного окна
        self.height, self.width = 1000, 600
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.height, self.width))
        pygame.display.set_caption("PyStrike")
        self.keys1 = KEYS1
        self.keys2 = KEYS2
        self.colors = [(0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (160, 82, 45)]
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()  # Группы спрайтов
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.single_sprites()
        self.live = 100

        self.run = True
        self.game_cycle()

    def game_cycle(self):  # Основной цикл игры
        while self.run:
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.run = False
            self.update_screen()
            self.collusion()

    def text_render(self, font_name, size, text, color, x, y):  # Рендеринг текста
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(font_name, size)
        text1 = font.render(text, True, color)
        self.screen.blit(text1, (x, y))

    def single_sprites(self):  # Спрайты
        global player, player2
        player = Player(x=200, y=self.width // 2, speed=5, a=0, l=300, colors=self.colors,
                        height=self.height,
                        width=self.width, screen=self.screen, keys=self.keys1, bullets=self.bullets, data=self.data,
                        rot_a=0, rotate_speed=1, all_sprites=self.all_sprites, a2=0)

        player2 = Player2(x=800, y=self.width // 2, speed=5, a=0, l=300, colors=self.colors,
                          height=self.height,
                          width=self.width, screen=self.screen, keys=self.keys2, bullets=self.bullets, data=self.data,
                          rot_a=0, rotate_speed=1, all_sprites=self.all_sprites, a2=0)
        self.all_sprites.add(player, player2)

    def update_screen(self):  # Обновление экрана
        self.screen.blit(self.background_img, (0, 0))
        self.fps_tracker()
        self.all_sprites.update()
        self.bullets.update()
        self.enemies.update()
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.bullets.draw(self.screen)
        self.enemies.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.update()

    def fps_tracker(self):  # Датчик FPS
        self.text_render("Arial Bold", 60, f"{str(self.clock.get_fps())[:2]}", self.colors[2], 0, 0)

    def collusion(self):  # Коллизия (не работает!!!!!!!!!)
        global player, player2
        self.text_render("Arial", 30, str(self.live), self.colors[3], 300, 0)
        collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player2, self.bullets, False)
        if collide:
            player2.kill()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  # Игрок 1
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed, a, l, colors, height, width, screen, keys, bullets, data, rot_a,
                 rotate_speed, all_sprites, a2):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.colors = colors
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.keys = keys
        self.screen = screen
        self.bullets = bullets
        self.all_sprites = all_sprites
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.data["tank"])
        self.new_image = self.image.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center).topleft
        self.speed = speed
        self.l = l
        self.a = a
        self.a2 = a2
        self.rot_a = rot_a
        self.rotate_speed = rotate_speed
        self.shooted = False
        self.rotate_ray = True

    def update(self):
        self.running()
        # self.ray_cast()
        self.rotate_sprite()

    def running(self):  # Метод отвечающий за расчеты движения
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[self.keys["up"]]:
            self.y += self.speed * math.sin((self.a * math.pi) / 180)
            self.x += self.speed * math.cos((self.a * math.pi) / 180)
        if keys[self.keys["down"]]:
            self.y -= self.speed * math.sin((self.a * math.pi) / 180)
            self.x -= self.speed * math.cos((self.a * math.pi) / 180)
        if keys[self.keys["left"]]:
            self.a -= 2
            self.a2 -= 2
        if keys[self.keys["right"]]:
            self.a += 2
            self.a2 += 2
        if keys[self.keys["shot"]]:
            self.shot()
            self.shooted = False
        if not keys[self.keys["shot"]]:
            self.shooted = True

    def ray_cast(self):  # Отрисовка лучей(В данный момент не используется)
        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, self.colors[3], (self.x + 100, self.y + 30),
                         (self.x + 100 + self.l * math.cos((self.a * math.pi) / 180),
                          self.y + 30 + self.l * math.sin((self.a * math.pi) / 180)))
        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, self.colors[2], (self.x + 100, self.y + 30),
                         (self.x + 100 + self.l * math.cos((self.a2 * math.pi) / 180),
                          self.y + 30 + self.l * math.sin((self.a2 * math.pi) / 180)))

    def shot(self):  # Выстрел (немного багованый)
        if self.shooted:
            bullet = Bullet(x=self.x + 120, y=self.y + 50, speed=10, colors=self.colors, a=self.a, r=10, a2=self.a2,
                            keys=self.keys)
            self.bullets.add(bullet)

    def rotate_sprite(self):  # Поворот спрайта и выравнивание по центру
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[self.keys["right"]]:
            self.rot_a -= 2
        if keys[self.keys["left"]]:
            self.rot_a += 2
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.new_image, self.rot_a)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.new_image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center).topleft


class Player2(Player):  # Игрок 2(наследуется от Игрок1)
    def __init__(self, keys, x, y, speed, a, l, colors, height, width, screen, bullets, data, rot_a,
                 rotate_speed, all_sprites, a2):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.data["tank"])
        self.new_image = self.image.copy()
        self.colors = colors
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.keys = keys
        self.all_sprites = all_sprites
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center).topleft
        self.screen = screen
        self.bullets = bullets
        self.speed = speed
        self.a = a
        self.a2 = a2
        self.rot_a = rot_a
        self.rotate_speed = rotate_speed
        self.l = l
        self.shooted = False
        self.rotate_ray = True


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  # Пули
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed, colors, a, a2, r, keys):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.colors = colors
        self.a = a
        self.keys = keys
        self.image = pygame.Surface((r * 2, r * 2))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.colors[2], (r, r), r)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, r, r)
        self.speed = speed
        self.a2 = a2

    def update(self):
        self.force()

    def force(self):  # Движение пуль
        self.rect.x += self.speed * math.cos((self.a2 * math.pi) / 180)
        self.rect.y += self.speed * math.sin((self.a2 * math.pi) / 180)


app = App()
```

Часть кода с ошибкой:

```
    def collusion(self):  # Коллизия (не работает!!!!!!!!!)
    global player, player2
    self.text_render("Arial", 30, str(self.live), self.colors[3], 300, 0)
    collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player2, self.bullets, False)
    if collide:
        player2.kill()
```

[ПОЛНАЯ ВЕРСИЯ КОДА СО ВСЕМИ ФАЙЛАМИ](https://github.com/coder6497/pygame/tree/master/pg_game)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.image.get_rect(center=self.new_image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center).topleft
```

вначале (до `.topleft`) вы создаёте `Rect`, затем берете его координаты, поэтому у вас получается не `Rect`, а кортеж из двух элементов (координаты объекта). чтобы это исправить  уберите `.topleft`